Get selected dropdown Item fields & values in SOLR in Sitecore
I created custom Sitecore index where I am able to generate the data in SOLR .
Now ,in the output of SOLR URL I have one ID which is a pointer /refence of dropdown , How I can fetch all fields & value of this dropdown ( not only item id alone)
I have given below path in SOLR config and build the Index
/sitecore/content/Global/Global/Data/datafolder
Please find more details in this screenshot
dd1 and dd2 are used as a dropdown field in CatagoryItem.
Here CatagoryItem fields & values are present in  SOLR search result along with dd1 and dd2 drop down item id , but how to fetch all fields +value of dd1 and dd2 with CatagoryItem

I used computed index field.
Details are added here
https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7227644148416139266/
